# How to understand how different requests are being provoked in Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, request, google-chrome-devtools

I have a web application, the backend is on Java, while the front end is using JS, how can I understand when I open dev tools how requests are being provoked, is there a part of the code which shows the order of execution of initial request when the website is loading. I am new to web programming and I don't understand how this process is working.

Comment: The 'initiator' column in devtools will give you a stacktrace for the event that triggered the request, but it's down to you to dig through the code to find what you need from there. There's nothing that's going to tell you the exact line of code in an event handler without some manual effort

Comment: If by *requests* you mean HTTPS requests, in Chrome devTools there is a **Network** tab, that tab contains a table of all HTTPS requests and it has a column named **Initiator** that indicates what initiated the request.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to resolve the issue by looking into the initiator tab and the stacktrace that is has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself will not tell you the other of the requests. Think of button1 triggering request1 and button2 triggering request2. If both buttons are shown to the user, then he may click on button1 first, then button2. Or button2 first, then button1. Or only button1. Or only button2. Or button1 and then button1 and then button2. Or none at all. As you can see, the requests to be sent, or their order is not necessarily deterministic.

But the good news is that you can open your dev tools, open the network tab, which shows what requests have been shown since the page load (or since your opening of dev tools if it happened later than loading the page) and the order of the requests by default is the order they were sent. So that should help you.